# "is written" (single or habitual action, tense choice)

Tags: grammar, tense, ambiguity

Let's consider the sentence containing the phrase "is written":

> How this word **is written**?

Does this phrase mean

1. Single action: a concrete situation, how the word was written once by someone?
2. Habitual action: the spelling of the word, i.e. how that word is usually written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By itself, your example sentence:

> - How this word is written?

is not standard English.

If this is a question, it should use **inversion**:

> - ✔️  How **is** this word written?

If this is a phrase, it depends on the context:

> *The two police officers looked at a word written on the sidewalk (graffiti).*
>
> - ✔️  Alice: I don't know *how this word is written* here.
> - Barb:  It looks like crayon.

Or:

> *The teacher pointed to the blackboard, which says "times".*
>
> - ✔️ Carol:  *How this word is written* depends on its usage.  If it refers to a newspaper, it should be capitalized, like "The Times".  If it refers to arithmetic, it should be lower-case, like "five times three".

Comment: So past participle "written" can mean any option: either single action or habitual?

Comment: Yes, and I think that is true generally:  *I have failed (once). I have failed (many times in my life).* *I have voted (once); I have voted (many times in my life).*

Comment: Thank you very much! By the way, your comment is important, you could add it the answer)